# C++ best way to save large array

Tags: c++

I want to create a class so save images.

```
class MyImage
{
public :
    int height;
    int width;
    int size;
    int matrix[];

    MyImage(int h, int w)
    {
        this->height = h;
        this->width = w;
        this->size = h * w;
        this->matrix = new int[size];
    }
}
```

But I got this error :

> field has incomplete type 'int []'

I've try to use vector but when I want to browse each pixel in an image 700x700, it take several time.

I've seen something about the `template<size_t>` but I don't know how to use it.

Or maybe using `int *` is better but I'll have manage memory by myself isn't it ?

Is it possible to create a int[0] and resize it in the constructor ?

What is the best way ?

Comment: Zero sized arrays are not supported by c++. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Even if your compiler supported zero sized arrays, you would still have to manage memory yourself.

Comment: In modern C++ you should use [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: dont use c-style arrays instead of `std::vector` to save time. It wont help. There must be some other issue that is eating up your time

Comment: "I've try to use vector but when I want to browse each pixel in an image 700x700, it take several time." why do you think, that using dynamically allocated memory for the same task will not take several time?

Comment: I've try with vector<int> but with image 700x700, it makes vector with more than 490,000 items. It take a long time to treat each pixel.

Comment: @A.Pissicat No matter what system you use to store your pixels, if your image is 700x700 pixels, you will have 490,000 pixels. That fact is independent of your memory management strategy.

Comment: You haven't given enough detail for us to understand what the performance issue. It's likely somewhere in how you are accessing the array, and not the storage itself.

Comment: `new int[h*w]` will create dynamic array with 490,000 items, why do you think that will solve your problem?

Comment: You did compile with the optimizer enabled?

Comment: @A.Pissicat -- *I've try with vector<int> but with image 700x700, it makes vector with more than 490,000 items. It take a long time to treat each pixel.*  -- A vector internally is nothing more than a contiguous block of memory, no different than you using `new[]`.  The internal block that vector maintains is easily pointed to by the `data()` member function.  So structurally there is no difference between your `new[]` call and what vector does, thus hard to believe that it takes any longer time to process pixels using vector's buffer and your `new[]` buffer.

Comment: You need to change `int matrix[];` to `int* matrix;`. But use a `std::vector<int>` instead (as the answers show).

Comment: how are you creating your vector ? can you please show the code.

Comment: Off-topic:  You don't need to use the `this->` syntax to access class members, unless the members have the same names as the parameters.  I recommend using different names between parameters and members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the best way ?

In your case if you know size at compile time, use `std::array`, if you do not use `std::vector` and initialize it properly. Creating memory manually would not give you anything, only headaches, `std::vector` does the same under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

It's C++, use std::vector

```
#include <vector>
class MyImage
{
public :
    int height;
    int width;
    std::vector<int> matrix;

    MyImage(int h, int w) : height(h), witdh(w), matrix(h*w)
    {
    }
}
```